# Matrix of $L(A)=A^{T}$ From $R^{2 \times 2} \rightarrow R^{2 \times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

A bit of trouble with this question:

Find the matrix of the linear transformation $L(A)=A^{T}$ From $R^{2 \times 2} \rightarrow R^{2 \times 2}$ with respect to the basis $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Do I need to run Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: What would Gram-Schmidt do for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the basis-matrices $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$.  We have
$$
L(v_1) = v_1\\
L(v_2) = v_2\\
L(v_3) = v_3\\
L(v_4) = -v_4
$$
It follows that the matrix of $L$ with respect to the basis is
$$
\pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&1\\&&&-1}
$$